# How do I convert a function $f(x)$ to $f(\frac{x}{a})$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, graphing-functions

I have a pretty simple problem but I kinda am confused. I have the function

$$f(x)_a = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{Aa}{x^2 + a^2}$$

And especially:
$$f(x=0)_a = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\cdot \frac{A}{a}$$

I have to plot it so that $\frac{x}{a}$ is on the abscissa - how do I accomplish that?

I thought of substituting $\gamma = \frac{x}{a}$ but then I'd have an x in there again which is zero...

Thanks for your help.
FunkyPeanut

Comment: $$\frac{Aa}{x^2+a^2} = \frac{A/a}{x^2/a^2+1} = \frac{A}{a(\gamma^2+1)} = g(\gamma)$$ ?

Comment: That looks good... Thank you very much. It is 4:30 in the morning here atm...